# C++ performance in large array

Tags: c++, performance, c++14, stdthread, large-data

I have large char array (614400) and hight performance video streaming application (100fps, 10ms for 1 frame).
In 1 frame I must modify my frame, and used for this 8 threads.

What is faster:
1. access every element in thread 1 by 1,
e. g. Thread1 (1,2,3, ... n)
      Thread2 (n+1, n+2, ... n*2)
      ...
2. access elements in next order:
   Thread1 (1,9,17 ...)
   Thread2 (2, 10, 18)
   ...
what way can be faster? now I have second method:

```
workers = new std::thread*[workersCount];
for ( int j = 0; j < workersCount; j++){
    workers[j] = new std::thread(&parameterController::extractPart, this, j*2, workersCount*2);
}
for ( int j = 0; j < workersCount; j++){
        workers[j]->join();
        delete workers[j];
    }
delete workers;
```

Comment: I suspect *measuring* will answer your question of what, if anything, is faster.

Comment: Do you create and destroy threads for each frame? o.O

Comment: I know, this is wrong way, but now no idea how to implement this. Now I look for init 8 infinity threads in constructor, that waiting for new frame. Any idea, how to catch, that threads waiting for new frame? cuz after this, i must do more with this data.

Answer (score 1):

Profile both and see the difference, that's the only way to be sure. I'd *guess* that having each thread produce a contiguous chunk will be faster due to prefetching and cache-friendliness, but only measurement can make you certain.

Comment: Yes, each thread must be created once, agree. Can u recommend numbers of threads? This value relative with CPU cores?

Comment: @Nick I'd say you should use GPU for that, CPU with that many threads.. well anything above  number of cores would have only  negative impact on performance, Non-server CPUs have form 4 to 16 cores.. GPU start with dozens and end with thousands. But in your case main performance impact done in creation and destruction of thread, not in access of array of pointers.